Goulds Well Jet Pump Adapter
I have an JL07N V-6 Well pump and I have developed a leak in the pipe before it hits the pipe.  It has a part # 3C15 or 3CL5 and has a 2 inch pipe coming into connection with 3 bolts and then two pipes come out.  One is offset and goes into the bottom of the Goulds and the other goes into the middle of the Goulds.  The leak is when it enters this object at the adapter with 3 bolts.
I am trying to identify the part in the picture to see if I can get a replacement or replace maybe its gasket.  I have heard it possible identified as a Goulds Packet Adapter
